# send text from UITextField to sms in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, uitextfield

I have a UITextField in which the user inputs some text. I want that text to be sent as sms when I hit the send button. The code I wrote is giving me problems. This is what I have so far.

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController,  MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var message: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


func canSendText() -> Bool {
    return MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()
}


func configuredMessageComposeViewController() -> MFMessageComposeViewController {

    let messageComposeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

    messageComposeVC.messageComposeDelegate = self
    messageComposeVC.body = message.text // This line doesn't work.
    return messageComposeVC
}


func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}



@IBAction func sendtext(sender: AnyObject) {

    let messageComposer = ViewController()

        // Make sure the device can send text messages
        if (self.canSendText()) {
            // Obtain a configured MFMessageComposeViewController
            let messageComposeVC = messageComposer.configuredMessageComposeViewController()


            var vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController

            vc?.presentViewController(messageComposeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)



        } else {
            // Let the user know if his/her device isn't able to send text messages
            let errorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Cannot Send Text Message", message: "Your device is not able to send text messages.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            errorAlert.show()
        }




}


}
```

Is there a way to copy all the contents of UITextField and paste in messageComposeVC.body? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the line

```
let messageComposeVC = messageComposer.configuredMessageComposeViewController()
```

to

```
let messageComposeVC = self.configuredMessageComposeViewController()
```

`messageComposer` is a new instance of your `ViewController` which doesn't have the message set. You are creating a new instance of ViewController in the line

```
var messageComposer = ViewController()
```

This has a new instance of the `message textField` which does not contain the text you entered.